# using 3rd party dll in enterprise web based application?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I found a great control with example [here](http://mattfrear.com/2010/05/19/jstree/) for mvc

It fulfills all my requirement but the problem is that it uses a js tree **dll**.

Should I go on and used that example in my application?
Do you people refrain from using 3rd party free dll in applications?
How will I tell that it will not expire or not cause problem later on

Forgive me if this is inappropriate question but thx in advance for any appropiate reply on this topic. just trying to get the point of view of you people on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your link, jsTree doesn't seem to use a DLL.  It looks like a series of javascript files that get included in your solution.

Answering the deeper question-- if the license and functionality fits what you're trying to accomplish, why *not* use a 3rd party component?  Keep in mind the following criteria when you make your choice:

- Suitability to purpose
- License / Cost
- Support

Compare that against the amount of time (and cost) it would be to develop the same solution yourself (or in-house).  Most of the time, the 3rd party component will win out.

Comment: dll is in the demo i downloaded from there